# Passing variables to an include page

Tags: php, variables, include

index.php:

```
<?php
$txt = 'Hello world';
include('display.php');
show();
?>
```

display.php:

```
<?php
//This works
echo($txt);

//This doesn't
function show(){
  echo($txt);
}

?>
```

How do i get the variable in the function to display?

Comment: Or read up on http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

This is a scope issue. Variables in the global namespace are not available inside of functions unless you explicitly make them so. There are three ways to do this:

**Pass them as a parameter** (recommended)

```
function show($txt){
```

**Use the `global` keyword** (strongly not recommended)

```
function show(){
    global $txt
```

**Use the `$GLOBALS` superglobal** (strongly not recommended)

```
function show(){
    $txt = $GLOBALS['txt'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a global variable inside a function, you have to use the `global` declaration:

```
function show() {
    global $txt;
    echo $txt;
}
```

The fact that it's in an include file is irrelevant, you have to do the same thing when the function is in the same file.

However, it's usually a better idea to pass variables as parameters, rather than accessing them as globals.